# Calling multiple URL with JavaScript AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an application that generate a hyperlink which user can click and automatically get login to the clicked link. for example the hyperlink is something like this https://www.externalapp.com/something/something/something

When user is clicked on the above link, if he doesn't have a previously open session to that app ([www.externalapp.com](http://www.externalapp.com)), he will get login to the app automatically based on some kind of SSO. However if user is already logged in, he will get prompted that multiple session is not supported, therefore he has to logout, and login again. So my question is can I use Ajax so when user is clicked on the hyperlink, first call the 
https://www.externalapp.com/logout and then 
calls the actual URL 
https://www.externalapp.com/something/something/something

If so, can you please provide a sample javascript that does that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do XHR cross-domain without CORs headers being set on the server.  I'd check first to see if the external app's logout url accepts a redirect parameter.  They often do.  If it does, just change the link to be the logout + redirect parameter set.  If that's not possible, you may be able to load the logout screen in an iFrame and then redirect to the sign-in screen via setTimeout a couple seconds later.  Unfortunately, if x-frame-options headers are set restrictively, browsers will not allow this either.